# Why is it that from version 5.9.1 to version 6.0 of the CMIS connectors disappear

Tags: alfresco, bonita

Why is it that from version 5.9.1 to version 6.0 of the CMIS connectors disappear and from version 6.1 there are only 6 connectors? I can not find solutions for the connectors that are eliminated. Someone can help me? I'm using BonitaSoft Comunity 7.6.3

Comment: Can you please be clearer about your problem ?

Comment: I had to migrate from Bonita 5.9.1 to version 7.6.3, and in version 5.9.1 there was the List a folder connector which returned all Alfresco repository and folders as seen at https://prnt.sc / j0tsw4. At this time in version 7.6.3 the available connectors are those found at http://prntscr.com/j0tvui.
How can I circumvent this situation since the existing connectors only send information to Alfresco. Which is why the connectors have disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

In Bonita latest version several CMIS connectors have been merged together. You should be able to perform all CMS operations (for Alfresco or others CMS) using the current set of CMIS connectors.